# C Program strcmp not working

Tags: c, linux, unix, strcmp

I'm a little confused on why the input isn't comparing with the "history" correctly. It seems to never go into the if statement no matter what I type. Once I type history it's suppose to go into the if statement. I tried using scanf("%s\n", input); also to see and that works correctly but not the way I want it to.

```
while(fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin) != NULL){

    filePrint = fopen(".simpleshell_history", "a");
    fileRead = fopen(".simpleshell_history", "r");      

    count++;
    fprintf(filePrint, "%d - %s", count, input);
    fclose(filePrint);

    if (strcmp(input,"history")==0){
        printf("%s\n", input);
        fseek(fileRead, 0, SEEK_SET);
        int x = 0;
        while ((x = fgetc(fileRead)) != EOF){
            printf("%c", x); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `fgets` leaves a newline at the end of the buffer.

Comment: newline is included in the `input`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you type "history\n", fgets() reads and stores the newline.  Try using either strncmp(input, "history", 7) or "strcmp(input, "history\n") in your if statement.

Comment: Thank you! Especially for the simple fix! :)

Answer (score 1):

fgets doesn't trim the new-line character from input. You'll need to do this yourself before using strcmp.

You can trim it by doing something like this:

```
input[strlen(input) - 1] = '\0';
```

Comment: This assumes `strlen(input)` is at least 1

Comment: Thanks for your help! This was the problem.